# Tailwind + SASS not rendering styles in Codepen

Tags: sass, tailwind-css, codepen

I'm playing around in Tailwind and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zIuAyLZPH0) [suggests](https://youtu.be/6zIuAyLZPH0?t=711) that you can avoid the repetition of Tailwind classes by using Sass like so:

HTML

```
<button class=but>Button</button>
```

SASS

```
.but {
    @apply bg-green-400 p-5 rounded-lg m-5 text-white
}
```

...but this isn't working for me; the styles don't get rendered and Codepen's CSS editor complains about a new line being expected. [Here's my pen](https://codepen.io/mitya33/pen/vYxPOjM) - it has Tailwind and Sass active.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using CDN Tailwind which cannot support a lot of features `@apply` included - it simply cannot generate your class on the fly

Documentation [says](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-via-cdn)

> Before using the CDN build, please note that many of the features that make Tailwind CSS great are not available without incorporating Tailwind into your build process.

- You can't customize Tailwind's default theme
- You can't use any directives like `@apply`, `@variants`, etc.
- You can't enable additional variants like `group-focus`
- You can't install third-party plugins
- You can't tree-shake unused styles